# How to print month name from MySQL timestamp count in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I count article view by timestamp month using json output. I have this code :

```
$value = array();
$stats  = Access::FETCH("SELECT COUNT(*) AS id FROM news_stats GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)");

foreach($stats as $key => $value){

   $rows2[] = $value['id'];

   }
echo json_encode($rows2);
```

output is : `NOTE: this is count for month each month`

```
["1","6"]
```

I need to print month name for this ouput like this:

```
["january","June"]
```

How do can in print month name ? Menaig is: `1 , 6` count from which month?

Comment: http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.date.php look at option "F"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This :

```
$value = array();
$stats = Access::FETCH("SELECT id, YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) AS `YEAR`, 
                MONTHNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) AS `MONTH`, 
                COUNT(*) AS id 
         FROM news_stats GROUP BY `YEAR`, `MONTH` ORDER BY `YEAR` DESC, `MONTH`");


foreach($stats as $key => $value){

   $rows2[] = $value['MONTH'];

   }
   echo json_encode($rows2);
```

Output is :

```
["June","August"]
```

Enjoy!!

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in MySQL itself by adjusting your query like so to use [`MONTHNAME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS id FROM news_stats GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTHNAME(date);
```

The only real value of doing it in PHP via an `mktime`/`date`combo is somehow your script needs the numerical value as well as the full month name itself. But that too could be addressed in MySQL by doing something like a `SELECT YEAR(date) as year, MONTH(date) as month,  MONTHNAME(date) as month_name…` but it all depends on coding needs more than anything.

Also, just realized it’s all coded for `GROUP BY` in your example. So perhaps this would work better:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS id,
YEAR(date) as `year`,
MONTH(date) as `month`,
MONTHNAME(date) as `month_name`,
FROM `news_stats`
GROUP BY `year`, `month`;
```

Comment: This still won't give him the monthname in his result set.

Comment: @JakeGould: jake i have a question: can list all month of the year and count by month, for each month print count if any month not have count show 0 like this : `["12","0","0","120","70","30","20","11","0","0","10","89"]` how do create this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use code similar to this in the foreach loop:

```
<?php
$monthNum = $value['id'];
$monthName = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $monthNum, 10));
?>
```

Took from: http://gilbert.pellegrom.me/php-month-number-to-month-name-the-easy-way/

Comment: The fundamental problem is with the query not returning any data about the month at all.  No amount of PHP date manipulation will solve that.